# How to refresh a QApplication using QWebEngineView every with an schedule period

Tags: python, pyqt5, refresh, schedule, qapplication

I'm trying to reload an URL in a given period using PYQT5, QWebEngineView, and schedule 
as far as I've search the code stops its execution after the app_exec(). So the 
"while" cicle and "scheduler" never gets executed.

as far as i have search there are diferent ways to reload the page (reload, refresh, repaint) but I'cant find the way to get this executed during the webpage execution.

any idea?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import schedule, time


def job():
    print('test')
    print('Reload :%s',time.time())
    browser.reload()
    browser.refresh()
    browser.sender().reload()
    browser.repaint()    


url ='http://www.google.com'

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
browser = QWebEngineView()
browser.load(QUrl(url))
browser.showFullScreen()

schedule.every(0.5).minutes.do(job)

sys.exit(app.exec_()) 

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`app.exec_()` is the event loop that allows the GUI to execute its tasks such as listening to events and updating the GUI states, the event loop is similar to a `while True: doSomething()`, so the code that is after it will only be executed if the GUI is finished running. On the other hand if you want to execute periodic tasks you must use `QTimer`:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

def job():
    print('test')
    print('Reload :%s',time.time())
    browser.reload() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url ='http://www.google.com'

    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    browser.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
    browser.show()
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=30*1000)
    timer.timeout.connect(job)
    timer.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```